# What is this circuit's function?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

I'm struggling to work out this circuit. In particular, I'm not sure what component the diode-like symbols represent.

It is related to a voltage adder using an op-amp, which I understand.

Comment: This component is a *Zener diode*

Comment: It is limiting the reverse-biased voltage on it to a set value (looks like 1.25V here). Other than that it is a pretty simple voltage divider circuit providing some tunable reference voltage.

Comment: More specifically, IC1 and IC2 are an integrated circuit that behaves the same as a high-precision zener diode. Could be [any of these](https://www.mouser.com/c/semiconductors/power-management-ics/voltage-references/?output%20voltage=1.25%20V&reference%20type=Shunt%20Precision%20References).

Comment: Input offset to null output of amplifier to 0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Zener diode looking symbol is probably representing a precision shunt reference. 1.25 volts is a common value for a shunt reference IC like [this part](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/SGST/SGST-S-A0004366744/SGST-S-A0004366744-1.pdf?hkey=52A5661711E402568146F3353EA87419): -

[image]

Plenty of manufacturers make devices like this so I expect the circuit symbol is for a precision reference rather than a proper Zener diode. Added to this is that I've never seen a Zener diode that has a voltage rating below around 2 volts hence, I believe it to be a precision shunt reference chip like above.

> *What is this circuit doing?*

[image]

I've added voltages to the image.

So the output potentiometer is capable of producing an output voltage (with respect to 0 volts) of up to +/- 1.25 volts depending on the values of R2 and R4.

Answer (score 6):

The diode-like or, more precisely, zener diode-like device is actually a voltage reference IC which works like a zener diode but gives a **much** more stable voltage across a much wider range of currents through it and is also much more temperature-stable (far less affected by changes in temperature). 
Such an IC is TS4061, for example, but it can be almost any other 1.25V shunt voltage reference IC.

The purpose of this circuit is to provide a very stable and accurate adjustable voltage on the output (potentiometer/trimmer slider) ranging from -1.25V to +1.25V compared to the 0V point/reference.

As the "Offset NULL" in the schematic would indicate, it is meant to provide an offset for a circuit it is connected to, in order to set a zero (0V) output when there is no signal or voltage on the input, or no voltage meant to be present at the output of that circuit under certain conditions.

Comment: Although it is not customary to do so here, I feel obliged to express my admiration for your answers. They are accurate and comprehensive and show that you understand circuits. I wish you to continue in the same direction.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Thank you, it's nice to have admirers and be appreciated. I always strive to be as correct and accurate as possible, to know and understand more, and to explain it as well and as clear as possible. I would say my brain functions as a self-teaching, self-correcting computer which can't stand to be wrong once it learns of its error, so it corrects it as soon as it's discovered/realized. Most of us are capable of that, but most take other things over facts, logic and accuracy as priorities, and thus surrender those computers to errors which keep on accumulating and taking hold.

Comment: @user253751 It depends on the models and purpose, as most voltage references are capable of 10mA, and many go up to 100mA (the venerable TL431). As their name suggests, they are not meant as regulators but merely voltage references which by definition don't need to provide any significant current. Zeners over time (many decades) have been needed in various circuits, at various power levels, and in the old times when simpler and less integrated circuits used more power, plus they are simpler and cheaper to produce, which has led to larger power models like 3W and 5W, and even much higher.

Answer (score 5):

### How do we understand circuits?

It is very useful for understanding circuits to try guessing how the one who designed (invented) them thought (something like a "mental reverse engineering":-) Let's try to do it with this circuit...

### Some guesses...

- The output of the circuit is taken after a resistor (R5) which leads us to think that this is a **current source**.
- The supply voltages are reduced and stabilized to very low values. So this source produces a **very small current**.
- The voltage applied to R5 is bipolar. So this source is a **bilateral current source**.

### What is it anyway?

It is a **precision low-current source** composed of three cascaded parts: a precision bipolar voltage source (R1,R3 and IC1,IC2), an adjustable voltage summer (R2,R4 and VR1), and a voltage-to-current converter (R5).

### What is its function?

Most likely, it is intended to inject/sink current to/from an op-amp input with the purpose to zero its output voltage
(more precisely, it does not enter/exit but is added/subtracted).

### Why is it precise?

It is a precision current source for two reasons:

- The "current-creating" input voltages are constant.
- The circuit output (after R5) is most likely connected to a summing point (op-amp inverting input) with zero voltage (virtual ground).

Thus everything in this circuit is constant. Only the potentiometer's output resistance changes when we turn its wiper but we watch the output voltage and adjust the potentiometer to zero it.

### Why is it done this way?

The problem here was to produce a very small (and stable) current.  This could hardly be done with the whole voltages because the resistor R5 would have a very high resistance. Therefore the voltages are reduced to a very small value and R5 is probably not very high.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as a voltage regulator which provides +1.25 and -1.25 V. There are ICs which do the same. The diode symbols are zener diodes which provide a constant voltage reference.